# I am new, I have a question about PyGame, OOP and Python in general

Tags: python, oop, pygame

I am new to programming , PyGame and OOP especially. I can't figure out how to make a button execute a specific command in PyGame. I tried making a class for a button, and if you look at this code,  I am able to execute the hover method/function as an example, but I am struggling to make the game close when I press the exit button. I can't seem to understand how to pass an argument that would make the main_menu be false for when exit is executed and main_game be true when play is executed.

```
from ColorsAndCoordinates import *

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 700))
font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 42)


class Button:
    main_menu = True

    def __init__(self, color, x, y, width, height, text):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.text = text

    def display(self, color):
        self.color = color
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))
        text = font.render(self.text, True, red)
        screen.blit(text, (self.x, self.y))

    def hover(self, color):
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if self.x + self.width > mouse[0] > self.x and self.y + self.height > mouse[1] > self.y:
            Button.display(self, color)

    def clicked(self):
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
            if self.x + self.width > mouse[0] > self.x and self.y + self.height > mouse[1] > self.y:
                pass


play_button = Button(blue, 200, 300, 95, 46, "Play")
exit_button = Button(blue, 700, 300, 95, 46, "Exit")
tutorial_button = Button(blue, 410, 550, 165, 46, "Tutorial")

main_menu = True
main_game = False
while main_menu:

    screen.fill(black)
    play_button.display(blue)
    exit_button.display(blue)
    tutorial_button.display(blue)
    play_button.hover(black)
    exit_button.hover(black)
    tutorial_button.hover(black)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            main_menu = False

    exit_button.clicked()

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: ***`Button.display(...`***: Should read `self.display(floor)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different solutions for this, for instance polymorphism, an action or an event.
An obvious and simple solution, is to add an `action` argument to the the method `clicked`. The argument is an action function, which is invoked when the button is clicked:

```py
class Button:
    # [...]

    def clicked(self, action = None):
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
            if self.x + self.width > mouse[0] > self.x and self.y + self.height > mouse[1] > self.y:

                if action:
                    action()
```

Create a function, which changes the states. Consider to use the [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#grammar-token-global-stmt) for the variables in global name space `main_menu` and `main_game`:

```py
def action_exit():
    global main_menu, main_game 
    main_menu = False
    main_game = True
```

Pass the action to the `exit_button.clicked`:

```py
while main_menu:
    # [...]

    exit_button.clicked(action_exit)
```

Furthermore changed `Button.display(self, color)` to `self.display(color)` in the method `display()`.

Complete example:

[image]

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 700))
font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 42)

red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)

class Button:
    main_menu = True

    def __init__(self, color, x, y, width, height, text):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.text = text

    def display(self, color):
        self.color = color
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))
        text = font.render(self.text, True, red)
        screen.blit(text, (self.x, self.y))

    def hover(self, color):
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if self.x + self.width > mouse[0] > self.x and self.y + self.height > mouse[1] > self.y:
            self.display(color)

    def clicked(self, action = None):
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
            if self.x + self.width > mouse[0] > self.x and self.y + self.height > mouse[1] > self.y:

                if action:
                    action()

def action_exit():
    global main_menu, main_game 
    main_menu = False
    main_game = True

play_button = Button(blue, 200, 300, 95, 46, "Play")
exit_button = Button(blue, 700, 300, 95, 46, "Exit")
tutorial_button = Button(blue, 410, 550, 165, 46, "Tutorial")

main_menu = True
main_game = False
while main_menu:

    screen.fill(black)
    play_button.display(blue)
    exit_button.display(blue)
    tutorial_button.display(blue)
    play_button.hover(black)
    exit_button.hover(black)
    tutorial_button.hover(black)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            main_menu = False

    exit_button.clicked(action_exit)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I have one question about this solution, when I do everything that is said the game just closes itself after I open it. I supposed I have done something wrong but I can't understand what.

Comment: Yea, I had done that exact thing, the game closes as soon as I open it.

Comment: Nvm I am an idiot, I had exit_button.clicked(action_ext()) instead of exit_button.clicked(action_exit), sorry and thank you!

Answer (score 1):

make main_menu and main_game  variable global inside your clicked function

```
    def clicked(self):
        global main_menu, main_game
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
            if self.x + self.width > mouse[0] > self.x and self.y + self.height > mouse[1] > self.y:
                main_menu = False
                main_game = True
```

Comment: The `Button` is used for different actions. How would you handle the actions for `tutorial_button` and `play_button`?

Comment: what action you want to take when tutorial_button and play_button get pressed

Comment: The point is you cannot distinguish if `exit_button.clicked()`, `tutorial_button.clicked()` or `play_button.clicked()` was called inside the `click` method.

Comment: for that we can use self.text....  if self.text perform this action

Comment: Sorry but that is an anti pattern. For each new button, you would have to implement an extra case in the method `clicked`. Please never choose such a design. There are different solutions for this, for instance polymorphism, an action or an event, ...

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that I wrote for another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57557599/why-wont-my-button-change-color-when-i-hover-over-it-pygame/57558056#57558056). I changed it to have a button quit the game:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

display_width = 1200
display_height = 600

# use python style variable names (lowercase)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Log In')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# load the font only once instead of every frame
font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 20)

# class name should be singular
class Button(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # 1) no need to have 4 parameters for position and size, use pygame.Rect instead
    # 2) let the Button itself handle which color it is
    # 3) give a callback function to the button so it can handle the click itself 
    def __init__(self, color, color_hover, rect, callback, text='', outline=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.text = text
        # a temporary Rect to store the size of the button
        tmp_rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, *rect.size)

        # create two Surfaces here, one the normal state, and one for the hovering state
        # we create the Surfaces here once, so we can simple blit them and dont have
        # to render the text and outline again every frame
        self.org = self._create_image(color, outline, text, tmp_rect)
        self.hov = self._create_image(color_hover, outline, text, tmp_rect)

        # in Sprites, the image attribute holds the Surface to be displayed...
        self.image = self.org
        # ...and the rect holds the Rect that defines it position
        self.rect = rect
        self.callback = callback

    def _create_image(self, color, outline, text, rect):
        # function to create the actual surface
        # see how we can make use of Rect's virtual attributes like 'size'
        img = pygame.Surface(rect.size)
        if outline:
            # here we can make good use of Rect's functions again
            # first, fill the Surface in the outline color
            # then fill a rectangular area in the actual color
            # 'inflate' is used to 'shrink' the rect
            img.fill(outline)
            img.fill(color, rect.inflate(-4, -4))
        else:
            img.fill(color)

        # render the text once here instead of every frame
        if text != '':
            text_surf = font.render(text, 1, pygame.Color('black'))
            # again, see how easy it is to center stuff using Rect's attributes like 'center'
            text_rect = text_surf.get_rect(center=rect.center)
            img.blit(text_surf, text_rect)
        return img

    def update(self, events):
        # here we handle all the logic of the Button
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        hit = self.rect.collidepoint(pos)
        # if the mouse in inside the Rect (again, see how the Rect class
        # does all the calculation for use), use the 'hov' image instead of 'org'
        self.image = self.hov if hit else self.org
        for event in events:
            # the Button checks for events itself.
            # if this Button is clicked, it runs the callback function
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and hit:
                self.callback(self)

run = True

# we store all Sprites in a Group, so we can easily
# call the 'update' and 'draw' functions of the Buttons
# in the main loop
sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
sprites.add(Button(pygame.Color('green'), 
                   pygame.Color('red'), 
                   pygame.Rect(150, 200, 90, 100), 
                   lambda b: print(f"Button '{b.text}' was clicked"),
                   'Press',
                   pygame.Color('black')))

def close(*args):
    global run
    run = False

sprites.add(Button(pygame.Color('dodgerblue'), 
                   pygame.Color('lightgreen'), 
                   pygame.Rect(300, 200, 90, 100), 
                   close,
                   'Close'))

while run:
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    # update all sprites
    # it now doesn't matter if we have one or 200 Buttons
    sprites.update(events)
    # clear the screen
    screen.fill(pygame.Color('white'))
    # draw all sprites/Buttons
    sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()
    # limit framerate to 60 FPS
    clock.tick(60)
```

We simply pass the `Button`-class a callback function that gets called if the button is clicked. For closing the window, we call a little function that captures the `run` variable and sets it to `False`.